# Incompatibility between enumitem and answers packages?

Tags: enumitem, answers

I am facing a strange problem while using the `enumitem` and `answers` packages. The following code compiles with no errors.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}    
\usepackage{answers}
\Newassociation{sol}{Solution}{ans}

\newlist{question}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[question,1]{label=\arabic*}

\begin{document}

\Opensolutionfile{ans}
\section{Problems}

\begin{question}
\item Question 1 \begin{sol}Solution 1\end{sol}
\end{question}

\Closesolutionfile{ans}

\section{Solutions}
\input{ans}

\end{document}
```

However, whenever I try to style the label in the list, `answers` throws a `TeX capacity exceeded, sorry` error.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}    
\usepackage{answers}
\Newassociation{sol}{Solution}{ans}

\newlist{question}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[question,1]{label=\textbf{\arabic*}}

\begin{document}

\Opensolutionfile{ans}
\section{Problems}

\begin{question}
\item Question 1 \begin{sol}Solution 1\end{sol}
\end{question}

\Closesolutionfile{ans}

\section{Solutions}
\input{ans}

\end{document}
```

Surely there must be a way to use these packages together?

Comment: Please edit your MWE so they can be compiled without having to add anything. Thee is no document class in these examples.

Comment: I can confirm this

Comment: Apologies, I have fixed this.

Answer (score 2):

The `answers` package does an automatic definition of the solution environment numbering/heading, defining `\Solutionlabel`, basically to be `\emph{Solution #1}`, `#1` being fed with `\textbf` --- which is wrong for another reason (due to the `label=\arabic*` way of enumitem, this can't work this way. Use `label={\bfseries \arabic*}` rather.

The trick is to redefine the `\Solutionlabel` to use the same labeling style, but this actually tedious, since it requires to define the list labelling and the solution label.

I recommend an question environment being theoremlike instead of an enumeration list.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{answers}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\Newassociation{sol}{Solution}{ans}


\newlist{question}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[question,1]{label={\bfseries \arabic*}} % defines questioni counter

\renewcommand{\Solutionlabel}[1]{\bfseries Solution \arabic{questioni}}

\begin{document}

\Opensolutionfile{ans}
\section{Problems}

\begin{question}
\item Question 1 \begin{sol}Solution 1 -- finally\end{sol}
\end{question}

\Closesolutionfile{ans}

\section{Solutions}
\input{ans}

\end{document}
```

[image]